# React datepicker custom styling

Tags: css, reactjs, date, datepicker

Greetings!

I'm having some trouble with styling react datepicker and wanted to check if anyone has had the same problem in their probject.

The issue is that I'm trying to style the selected date (beginning and end) as a ring that overlaps the date range like so.

[image: Desired results]

Once I ad a border radius to the beginning and end dates then the background color from the date picker comes visible.

This is basically what's happening and the markup from the react datepicker package.

[image: Current issue]

I'm out of ideas how this can be solved with css :/

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Steinar

Comment: What if you add a horizontal gradient on 1 that splits bg color in the middle white to blue?

Comment: try something like this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/25958412/1275832

Comment: although you might have to add extra divs to make your style work, if you dont want use background images/svgs.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will try it out :)