# CSS Help for HR Stylying

Tags: css

I need to work out how to achieve the styling of the design below using an HR tag. The HR needs to be two colours and also have the angle between. I'd prefer if I could achieve this with pure CSS. No IMG files.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

[image]

```css
hr{
position:relative;
height:3px;
background-color:#7902AA;
}

hr:before {
position:absolute;
content : ' ';
left:0;
right:0;
height:3px;
top:-1px;
background-color:#FFD800;
}
```

```html
<h1>
The Equality Network is an independent organisation founded to establish LGBTIQ+ inclusivity in the workplace and broader community.
</h1>
<hr>
<p>
The Equality Network has pioneered a new benchmark in acceptable standards for LGBTIQ+ inclusivity training in the workplace and community. 
</p>
```

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+css+box+with+two+colors%2C+slanted&tbm=isch) of [Use linear gradient in CSS to split div in 2 colors but not in equal halves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25958412/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()) with multi-position color stops and a 135 degree angle:

```css
hr {
  height: 0.25em;
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, yellow 0% 50%, purple 50% 100%);
}
```

```html
<hr>
```